# Python Scrapy - service_identity(opentype) not working and cannot install

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Python and linux beginner trying to get scrapy up and running. Following the instructions and code from https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html. Getting user warning `You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'cannot import name 'opentype'`

downloaded and tried to install `service_identity` but got `Requirement already satisfied` on the different parts of the install. Tried both pip3 and download and install from `.whl` file downloaded from the `pypi-URL` below.

python 3.5.3 on lubuntu 17.04 on virtualbox

```
mat@mat-VirtualBox:~$ scrapy startproject tutorial2
:0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'cannot import name 'opentype''.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
New Scrapy project 'tutorial2', using template directory '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/templates/project', created in:
    /home/mat/tutorial2

You can start your first spider with:
    cd tutorial2
    scrapy genspider example example.com
mat@mat-VirtualBox:~$ pip3 install Downloads/
geckodriver-v0.19.1-linux64.tar.gz
NOOBS_lite_v2_4.zip
npm-debug.log
phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/
phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
reveal.js-master.zip
service_identity/
service_identity-17.0.0.dist-info/
service_identity-17.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
mat@mat-VirtualBox:~$ pip3 install Downloads/service_identity-17.0.0
Invalid requirement: 'Downloads/service_identity-17.0.0'
It looks like a path. Does it exist ?
mat@mat-VirtualBox:~$ pip3 install Downloads/service_identity-17.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl 
Requirement already satisfied: service-identity==17.0.0 from file:///home/mat/Downloads/service_identity-17.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pyopenssl>=0.12 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1-modules in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pyopenssl>=0.12->service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=2.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from pyopenssl>=0.12->service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyopenssl>=0.12->service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyopenssl>=0.12->service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyopenssl>=0.12->service-identity==17.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography>=2.1.4->pyopenssl>=0.12->service-identity==17.0.0)
mat@mat-VirtualBox:~$
```

trying anyway to see what happes

```
mat@mat-VirtualBox:~/tutorial2$ scrapy crawl qoutes
:0: UserWarning: You do not have a working installation of the service_identity module: 'cannot import name 'opentype''.  Please install it from <https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity> and make sure all of its dependencies are satisfied.  Without the service_identity module, Twisted can perform only rudimentary TLS client hostname verification.  Many valid certificate/hostname mappings may be rejected.
2017-12-06 19:35:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: tutorial2)
2017-12-06 19:35:52 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial2', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial2.spiders'], 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial2.spiders'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 69, in load
    return self._spiders[spider_name]
KeyError: 'qoutes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 156, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 57, in run
    self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 167, in crawl
    crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 195, in create_crawler
    return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 199, in _create_crawler
    spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 71, in load
    raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
KeyError: 'Spider not found: qoutes'
mat@mat-VirtualBox:~/tutorial2$
```

code in my /home/mat/tutorial2/tutorial2/spiders/qoutes_spider.py

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
```

Comment: did you try to install as root/admin - with sudo ?

Comment: maybe you have to install `OpenSSL` first - [this page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/service_identity) shows that `service_identity` uses `pyOpenSSL` which may need `OpenSSL` (and this is not python module so you have to instal with `apt`)

Answer (score 16):

Your issue seems to be a typo. You are using `qoutes` and `quotes`. Swapping `o` and `u`. Also for `service_identity` is a warning as such. If you want to install it try using

```
pip3 install service_identity --force --upgrade
```

Comment: The `--force --upgrade` fixed the problem for me, because even though I installed `service_identity` previously it still wasn't working because its dependent libraries weren't up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the author of this question.

This command fixed it:

```
pip install service_identity --force --upgrade
```